How can i make a simple visualization of my result from a two way fixed effects regression model?
I am trying to understand the effect of the variable x1 on the dependent variable y1, and for that i have panel data. I decided to use a two way fixed effects model to estimate the effect of variable x1. I also add other time-varying and unit varying variables as controls.
I then ran my regression models, and got the coefficient i was interessed it. However, when it came to reporting the results i started wondering how one could graph these results in a way that reported the findings in a simple manner. I was thinking if it was possible to create something along the lines of a standard scatterplot for the relationship between Y1 and X1 and a regression line based on my two way fixed effects model. But since im pretty new to two way fixed effects models and panel data in general, i just couldn't figure out how to do this properly when working with two-way fixed effects model and panel data, and even if it was possible. So is it possible? And if not, how is results normally reported when working with two way fixed effects models, when your primarily interested in the effect of one variable (x1) on the dependent variable?

Marginal effects plots
